# Use converter without path

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I use a converter without a binding path? I've got some radio buttons and would like to have a converter that is passed a string and that then returns whether or not a checkbox is checked:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LanguageToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter='de_DE'}" Command="{Binding ChangeLanguageCommand, ElementName=LangSelector}" CommandParameter="de-DE">
```

However, I get the error message `Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.`

Comment: Did you try setting the `BindingMode` to one-way? Not sure that will fix the issue though, just a suggestion.

Comment: is your converter got hit ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you need to specify path to current `DataContext`

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource LanguageToBoolConverter}, ..."
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current source. For example, Text="{Binding}" is equivalent to Text="{Binding Path=.}".

Comment: Perfect! Thank you alot! Though I don't get why adding an OPTIONAL period (.) is the solution.. Thanks for linking to MSDN, I'll read up there :o)

Comment: Basically when you use `Conveter` it requires `Path=` part. It no longer assumes that it's current binding source and the way to say manually that path is current binding source is to use `Path=.`